# system collections specialized not found

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, c++-cli

Trying to compile a c++/cli program using VS 2008 and .NET framework 3.5

These statements work:

```
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
```

but the specialized collection namespace doesn't show up

```
using namespace System::Collections::Specialized;
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some assembly I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it mostly lives in System.dll which is always added by a project template.  Virgin C++/CLI project with no assembly references added:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify "system" in the references and this fixed it